# How To Expand A Parent Div Height to Fill It's Containing Parent

Tags: html, css, responsive

This should be simple, but I'm having trouble getting this to work.

I simply want the lime colored background to expand and fit 100% of the current height of it's parent container (IE: the magenta colored part). Here it is in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/L973mmva/

Here's the code:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 80%; background-color:magenta;">

        <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:25%;">
            <img src="http://www.bjbzryl.com/data/out/7/780401.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
        </div>

        <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:73%; margin-left:2%; background-color:lime;">
            <p style="float:left; display:inline-block; margin:2% 2% 2% 2%;">blah blah blah</p>
        </div>


        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the inner div to 100%? If that doesn't work then also set a pixel height in the outer div along with the 100% for the inner div

Comment: Hi Chris. That won't really work because then the main container (with the magenta background) might extend below the picture. I could see how that might work with some fiddling. The "flex" approach given by others seems the best fit right now. I'm just concerned about whether or not "flex" is respected by all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it to `flex` and the flex children will match the height of the parent, and you can remove the `inline-block`, `float`, and your clearfix code, too.

```html
<div style="width:100%;">
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 80%; background-color:magenta; display: flex;">

    <div style="width:25%;">
      <img src="http://www.bjbzryl.com/data/out/7/780401.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
    </div>

    <div style="width:73%; margin-left:2%; background-color:lime;">
      <p style="float:left; display:inline-block; margin:2% 2% 2% 2%;">blah blah blah</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the browser doesn't support flex? IE 11 has problems last time I checked.

Comment: @ChrisSharp flex has 96% global support http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox and it works fine in IE10/11, there are just a couple of considerations to keep in mind with shorthand properties, but I'm not using them here. A non-flex approach would be to use `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-cell;` on the children instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm just getting into flex and that was helpful.

Comment: @MichaelCoker This seems so simple... I almost feel it's too good to be true. I'm taking it on your word that I can use this "flex" property in this context and not worry about it breaking in a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use flex instead of float:

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 80%; background-color:magenta;display:flex;">
     
      <div style="width:25%;display: inline-block;">
       <img src="http://www.bjbzryl.com/data/out/7/780401.jpg" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      
      <div style=" margin-left:2%; background-color:lime; flex: 1;">
       <p style="float:left; display:inline-block; margin:2% 2% 2% 2%;">blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
       
     
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      
     </div>
```

Comment: For the second div you do not need to set `width: 73%;` . only `flex: 1;` is enough to fix this cover the remained space.

Comment: Thanks Farzin. I've been working with your and Michael's suggestions, using flex. The only issue i've come across so far is what to do about rearranging divs on mobile. IE: positioning the right block below the left one on phone viewports. Making width: 100% for each doesn't do this as flex seems to find ways to recaculate to keep everything floating inline.

Comment: @Snik ; The only thing you need is useing **flex wrap** . For the flex div (display: flex) add this: `flex-wrap: wrap; -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;`. And also set a `min-width` for the right block div(flex: 1;) .. `min-width: 150px;`

Comment: cool I will try that. I noticed a new problem that popped up. When declaring the document as <!DOCTYPE html> at the very top it prevents the image on the left from filling the left div. Any idea why that is?

Comment: If you google this: **doctype html breaks css** you will find multiple related posts. If they can not solve your problem, ask this as a new question.